# How does a project time estimation changes by adding more programmers?

Tags: time, time-estimation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Estimating a project with many unknowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972640/estimating-a-project-with-many-unknowns)

We have an estimation about our project time by man/hour. Now we want to know how much our project will take if we have more than one programmer? Do you have any idea how to estimate this? Any formula?

Comment: [Division](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29)?

Comment: Please search here and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions for all of the questions on estimation.  After reading all those questions, please **update** yours to not duplicate all the other identical questions.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972640/estimating-a-project-with-many-unknowns is identical to this question.

Comment: At least the time will not decrease ten times if you assign 10 coders. Some time will go to interaction, team works etc

Comment: Multiply by 1.5 if they don't like eachothers programming style

Comment: When a programmer estimates time, multiply by 4 and use the next larger unit to get a realistic timeframe. 1 hour -> 4 days. 1 week -> 4 months.

Comment: Have a look at Brook's Law: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27s_law

Comment: You can also search on the [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/) site for answers to similar questions.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the estimation in man-hour, you just have to divide that number by the number of people working on it to get the number of hours it will require.

So a 6 man-hour project will take 6/1 = 6 hours with 1 programmer, 6/2 = 3 hours with 2 programmers.

I think wikipedia has a good article on this topic : see [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-hour)

*EDIT: ok since people tends to make me believe this is more than a "use of the man-hour system" question, here is some more tips :*

To manage a project with more accuracy than the system you have multiples tools that can help your. Many of them are included in project management systems.

First of all you need to identify sub units of the development. Then you'll be able to make a GANTT chart with dependencies that will build a structure in your project.

By doing so, and assigning people to sub units, you can by the mean of man-hour system **estimate** the time required for this particular unit. Then the different constrains put up by dependencies, vacation days (and so on), will give you the estimate date of end of works.

GANTT also allow you to work backwards: setting up constraint on end of project and using the dependencies constraints to compute the beginning date of your project.

Pieces of software that will help you do that are (non exhaustively) MS Project, Gantt project (open source) and surely a lot more.

You can also look on different tools use by project managers : PERT chart, activity diagram and many other I do not use and/or know about.

I hope this provides more useful help than the previous edit.

Comment: Read the [mythical man month](http://www.amazon.com/Mythical-Man-Month-Software-Engineering-Anniversary/dp/0201835959) for why this is not so. Each person you add, adds another person to communicate with. Humans do not share brains like processes on a computer share RAM :)

Comment: Comment: Man-hour does not care about pauses etc... it's pure work.

Comment: If it takes 1 person 8 hours to build a wall, it does not take 8*60 persons just one minute to build the same wall...

Comment: Of course, it's just an estimation, and the man-hour system does not allow you to be more precise. You can go on some project management tools to get more accurate.

Comment: 9 women cannot get a baby in one month...

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I get it (Please refer to further edits).